# Open drawer in another pages

Tags: flutter, drawer

My drawer is in my main.dart file. and I want to open the drawer with another page. of course Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer(); not worked.  But I have no idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a public drawer like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class PublicDrawer extends StatefulWidget {
  PublicDrawer({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PublicDrawerState createState() => _PublicDrawerState();
}

class _PublicDrawerState extends State<PublicDrawer> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

and at your all other page, use scaffold to implement your drawer:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:~~~~~~~/Widgets/drawer.dart';

class ProfilePage extends StatefulWidget {
  ProfilePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ProfilePageState createState() => _ProfilePageState();
}

class _ProfilePageState extends State<ProfilePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        drawer: PublicDrawer(), <----
        body: Container(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a component out of your drawer and put your new page (or the page you want to open your drawer in) in it's own scaffold (and not a component by itself)
then import your drawer and insert it in the scaffold drawer. =)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap Your Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer();
Button Or IconButton or any thing you are using With Builder Widget This Will Fix The Issue
Like This:

```
leading: Builder(builder: (context) {
              return IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer();
                },
                icon: SvgPicture.asset(
                  "assets/icons/menu.svg",
                  width: 20,
                ),
              );
            })),
```